# Inline Aseembly What do I do about an "Illegal instruction (core dumped)"

Tags: inline, inline-assembly

Are there anything wrong with below inline assembly code?
I encountered "Illegal instruction (core dumped)" when running the function spinlock_lock.

```
void spinlock_lock(struct spinlock * lock) {

    int a;
    __asm__ __volatile__("movl %0, %%eax;"
                         "test %%eax, %%eax;"
                         "jnz spinlock_lock;"
                         :"=r"(a)
                         :"r"(lock->cmos_lock)
                         :"eax");

    __asm__ __volatile__ ("lock; cmpxchg %%edx, %0\n"
                          :"=r"(a)
                          :"r"(lock->cmos_lock)
                          :"edx", "memory");
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your branch; normally (x86) [the called function will save the frame pointer on the stack before executing any other code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#x86).

Your `jnz spinlock_lock` branch will branch back to the **entry point of the entire function** and thus save the frame pointer again before getting back to your inline assembler. Save the frame pointer enough times, you'll run out of stack. Not to mention that if you leave your inline assembler by branching outside it, your registers may no longer contain what you think they do.

You should probably put a label inside your inline assembler and branch back to that instead.

Also, the instruction `cmpxchg %edx, %0` can operate against a register, but cannot be combined with `lock` since you're using a register operand. To make `lock cmpxchg` work, you need to change the matching parameter constraint from `r` to `m`.

You may want to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746344/illegal-instruction-in-asm-lock-cmpxchg-dest-src) for a discussion of `lock cmpxchg` requiring a memory operand or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6935581/477878) for an alternate gcc implementation of spinlock without the assembler.

Comment: you are talking about his?__asm__ __volatile__("L: " "movl %0, %%eax;"
        "test %%eax, %%eax;"
//        "jnz spinlock_lock;"
        "jnz L;"
    ://"=r"(a)
    :"r"(lock->cmos_lock)
    :"eax");

Comment: @dykw Yes, your jnz will branch back to the function entry point, you should keep the branching within your inline assembler code.

Comment: it doesn't work. I try to comment "__asm__ __volatile__ ("lock; cmpxchg %%edx, %0\n"". The illegal instruction disappear. Why?

Comment: @dykw Added some details on that to the answer.